# Imagemagick skew image with 4 (x,y) coordinates

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have 4 (x,y) coordinates between which I want place image as example given below.

The whole image must be placed within this area without cropping.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

Using this 800x600 balloon:

[image]

You can use a *"Perspective Distort"* like this:

```
convert balloon.jpg -matte -virtual-pixel transparent  \
  -distort Perspective '0,0,50,0 0,599,100,599 800,0,750,100 800,600,500,500' result.png
```

There are basically 4 pairs of points in the parameters,i.e.

```
Pt1X,Pt1Y,Pt1NewX,Pt1NewY Pt2X,Pt2Y,Pt2NewX,Pt2NewY Pt3X,Pt3Y,Pt3NewX,Pt3NewY Pt4X,Pt4Y,Pt4NewX,Pt4NewY
```

So the command above moves point `0,0` to `50,0` and moves point `0,599` to `100,599` and so on.

[image]

I have labelled each of the points in red and drawn the path along which each one has moved in green.

Comment: how you calculated 4 xy coordinates values to place image. Can you please explain this command. I want to know how I will put image on my 2nd example.

Comment: I'm not sure what you don't understand - I have added a red border now so you can see the extent of the image. The top-left corner (0,0) has moved 20 pixels to the right and is now at (20,0).

Comment: It would be helpful to explain if you provide two separate images --- the input and the desired output. The coordinates are not computed. They are measure in the input image and usually in the output image from the corners or the image or some object within the image. That makes 4 x,y pairs for the input and 4 x,y pairs for the output. The order is inx1,iny1 outx1,outy1 ... inx4,iny4 outx4,outy4. If you do not have an output to measure, you can do perspective transformation via rotation angle. See my script 3Drotate at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php

Comment: Thanks to both of you for giving valuable time. Please check the new example I added.

Comment: See duplicates question and solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50491068/how-to-do-four-point-distort-with-imagemagick