# Imagemagick: crop non-symmetrical corners, then warp?

Tags: imagemagick

I've got some scanned images of old maps, where the map is not always square within the scan, and usually has a border of "dead space" around it in the scan. I want to remove this border and rotate the map, so its edges are the edge of the final image.

I have identified the pixel coordinates of the corners of the map within the image: let's say they're at [5, 5], [1000, 7], [992, 600],  and [3, 594].

Now I want to crop the image to those coordinates exactly (which will probably mean it's not quite a rectangle any more) and then warp and rotate it so it becomes a perfect rectangle again.

Is this possible with imagemagick, or any other command line image tool?

UPDATE: I'm using ImageMagick 7.0.7-31 Q16 x86_64 on OSX. Images to follow...

Comment: Yes, it is possible with ImageMagick using +distort perspective. But you need to provide the desired corresponding output coordinates that would be rectangular or square. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#perspective. The coordinate pair are inx1,iny1 outx1,outy1 ... Please identify your ImageMagick version and platform. Syntax can be different. If you post an example image and the coordinates for input and output, I can show you the command line.

Comment: You can see how to do that here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/50250877/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell awesome, thanks!