# How to do four point distort with Imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to place a logo on a image. I have 4 (x,y) coordinates. The logo should be placed between this area only with some skew effect as given below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always best to provide clean separate input imagery (in a addition to your result) and your ImageMagick version and platform.

Nevertheless, I cropped out the two images as:

[image]

[image]

Then I measured the corner coordinates of the G image clockwise from the top left corner.

Then I measured the colored circle coordinates in similar order (green, red, pink, blue).

Then I did the +distort perspective and composited the two images. The sequence of coordinates is: inx1,iny1 outx1,outy1 .... inx4,iny4 outx4,outy4, where the G image is the in and the bag image is the out.

Here is the command in unix ImageMagick 6 syntax. For Windows remove the \s. For ImageMagick 7, use "magick" rather than "convert"

```
convert bag.png \( G.png -virtual-pixel none +distort perspective "0,0 75,280  116,0 155,311  116,119 141,367  0,119 64,329" \) -layers flatten +repage result.png
```

[image]

Reference: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#perspective

EDIT:

If you make the white background of the G image transparent, then it will look better.

```
convert bag.png \( G.png -fuzz 15% -transparent white -virtual-pixel none +distort perspective "0,0 75,280  116,0 155,311  116,119 141,367  0,119 64,329" \) -layers flatten +repage result2.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I know this is old, but if you're still around, what is meant by 'In' and 'Out' here?

Comment: in are coordinates in the input and out are the corresponding coordinates in the output